# what is required to get an overlay window using x11 protocol with no compositor running?

Tags: c, common-lisp, overlay, x11, composite

Using the lisp implementation of the X11 protocol, get-overlay-window freezes when no compositor is running. If I kill the lisp process, the xid is printed out.
This also freezes my lisp window manager running in another lisp thread, though same process.  Basically X acts like it's been grabbed, so thank god for ctrl-alt-f1.

Some previous questions about composite show others running into similar problems when no compositor is running.

I'm guessing that maybe the server is waiting for some sort of out of protocol authorization or something? Or something particular sequence of events has to be completed?

Having access to the overlay window when another compositor is active isn't helpful for writing a compositor!

Comment: To test window managers inside other managers you can use nested X11 servers like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr

Comment: I'm not seeing how that will help as I'm trying to get it to work without any window managers besides my own running.

Comment: Sorry if that didn't help. Could post a minimal reproducible example in order to better understand what you are trying to achieve and what is blocking you? Thanks.

Comment: Ugh that's quite the bug. File it with your X11 client library.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had a reading comprehension fail with the protocol description, or they a writing fail.

Asking composite to redirect windows automatically ensures the windows contents get drawn. It does not ensure they get drawn to the overlay! Nor does the overlay appear to be transparent. So even with setting all windows to be automatically updated, when the overlay window gets mapped by the call to get its XID it blocks you from seeing any other updates to the screen and blocks all input.

Making the overlay in a sense not very useful. Or the request to have automatic updates for redirected windows not useful.  Either way, seems will have to paint every single pixel even of the windows we're not interested in.

Maybe it's just a driver thing?